# Identifying user - email, phone number, FB and gmail?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app but I wanted a way to uniquely identify the user. However I dislike the idea of creating username and password since I find that will be inconvenient for the user.
The alternative that I was thinking was,
1. Facebook login
2. Gmail login,
3. Email id
4. Phone number

My question is - Is It legal to display the a user's email id or phone number to other users?
And, in general ur comments on whats the best approach.
My app does require that users be able to contact each other somehow.

Thanks in advance. I would appreciate you any insights you can give.
-Vishal

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use UUID (UUID: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Android provides classes to generate UUID. You can generate this at the time of installation and save it.
Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned this..but I plan to port this app to iPhone as well..which I don't know if it supports UUID

Answer (score 0):

> Is It legal to display the a user's email id or phone number to other users?

**Its against privacy**. And its not a good practice to display it with user consent as well. Its a step taken against spamming.